# match part of HTML with regex

Tags: android, regex, jsoup

i need help to match the Numbers after the Version part of this website.
http://apk-dl.com/com.ochs.pipette/

```
 <div>
    <span>Version: </span> 7.01.0.669
 </div>
```

I'am use Jsoup to get the Website and filter it to this tag .

```
Jsoup.connect("http://apk-dl.com/" + packageName)
                    .timeout(30000)
                    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6")
                    .referrer("http://www.google.com")
                    .get()
                    .select("div[class=info]")
                    .last();
```

Can i specialize it with Jsoup or can somebody help with a regex to match it?

Answer (score 1):

```
Version:\s<\/span>\s([0-9\.]+)

Version: matches the characters Version: literally (case sensitive)
\s match any white space character [\r\n\t\f ]
< matches the characters < literally
\/ matches the character / literally
span> matches the characters span> literally (case sensitive)
\s match any white space character [\r\n\t\f ]
1st Capturing group ([0-9\.]+)
    [0-9\.]+ match a single character present in the list below
        Quantifier: + Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
        0-9 a single character in the range between 0 and 9
        \. matches the character . literally
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Version:\s<\/span>\s(.*)
```

I use something like this, because need to match something like this 1.0-build1 or other funny variations. Need to test in the app.